# Convert .kv class to .py class

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to convert the following into class of the same in .py, help me understand how to convert please or how I would call this class in .py without conversion as it is not the root of the app.

```
<LoadDialog>:
BoxLayout:
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    orientation: "vertical"
    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        path: './'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        Button:
            text: "Cancel"
            on_release: root.cancel()
        Button:
            text: "Load"
            on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy module will read and parse the *.kv file automatically if the *.kv file name matches your app class name.

Example 1: if your app class is like this:

```py
class MyApp(App):
    pass
```

The *.kv file that kivy module will be looing for: `my.kv`

Example 2: if your app class is like this:

```py
class SomeApp(App):
    pass
```

The *.kv file that kivy module will be looing for: `some.kv`

[Here](https://youtu.be/AS3b70pLYEU?t=299) is a nice tutorial video that you can watch.

Answer (score 0):

Install kivy package in your system

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string(
    <Enter kv code here>
)
```

try this